# on('click' 'li' function() whitespace added automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, whitespace

I write a program like Livesearch and use click li and added li data in the input field automatically. But when i click on li some whitespaces on begining and at the end automatically added. The given below is the jquery script code.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mobilenumber">Mobile Number</label>

          <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" id="getNum" placeholder="Enter number">
        </div> 
        <div id="printThis">
        </div>   
      </div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getNum').keyup(function() {
   var search = $(this).val();
   if(search !== ""){
    
   $.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url('shop_admin/getNum')?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: {search: search},
    success: function(response){ 
      // Add response in Modal body
      $('#printThis').fadeIn();
      $('#printThis').html(response);
      // Add response in Modal body
    }
  });
 }else{
  $('#printThis').html("");
 }
});    
});
  $(document).on("click",'li',function(){
      $('#getNum').val($(this).text());
      $('#printThis').fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

I dont know where the mistake.

Comment: use : `.trim()` here : `$(this).text().trim()`